# Is this circuit block diagram correct?

Tags: led, capacitor, filter, supercapacitor

I plan to build a flashlight powered by 360F 2.7V super capacitor (proposed to be charged to max 2.5V and discharged to min voltage of around 0.6V to increase capacitor life). The EMF generated by the 200 step stepper motor is around 10V peak when rotated at around 300 RPM. I have tried to draw the circuit block diagram.

[image]

Is this circuit going to work? Do I need a filter here? What parameters do I need to keep in mind for selection of different components considering the drop across rectifier diodes is between 0.8V to 1.4V?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with a buck converter to charge the capacitor.  Just connect the output of the full wave bridges directly to the capacitor and use a shunt regulator to make sure the voltage doesn't go above whatever level you want.  Just a zener diode might do.

You don't really care what the load on the motor is when the capacitor is already full.  Besides, stepper motors are pretty crappy generators, so you probably won't notice much of a load change on the shaft anyway.

Also, are you sure your boost converter can run from only 600 mV in?  That's quite low.  A bootstrap supply might help.  This means the boost converter needs a higher voltage to get going, but once it does, it makes its own power supply voltage so that it can work to a very low input voltage.  Basically the boost converter electronics get power from the same voltage the LED is being run at, with only the input power coming from the capacitor.  There will also be a Shottky diode from the cap to the LED so that when the cap is at 2.5 V, the boost converter has 2 V or more to operate on.  You can definitely make a boost converter that runs from that initially, and then over 3 V once it starts up and runs the LED.

Comment: Thanks @Olin Lathrop for your reply. The only reason for choosing between a buck converter and a regular voltage regulator is the  high efficiency of the former. Since it is a low power application, I wish to minimize the losses as much as possible. And, as for choosing 600 mV, it is chosen to extract from capacitor as much juice as I can to power the load for longer. It can be increased to 1 V if it is really difficult to work at 600 mV. Also, I assume filter is not needed here. I do not know whether there is scope for any improvement in the circuit. If it is, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @omsai: I can see efficiency from cap to LED mattering, but not generator to cap.  If you really cared about that, you'd be using a real generator, not a stepper motor in reverse.

Comment: So instead of using stepper motor, is it better idea to use some small dc motor as generator? Will it perform efficiently? I was planning to build a small axial flux generator but due to lack of availability of various generator parts, I dropped the idea. And then, I stumbled upon an old stepper motor, so thought of using it for this application. I am novice here and I don't know much but I am very hungry for the knowledge.

Comment: @omsai: You still haven't made a case why generator to cap efficiency matters.  Presumably a human is cranking this thing, and it won't matter what the load is on the shaft over a reasonable range.  You need 1.5 kJ.  Over 1 minute charge time, that's only 21 W.  If that were 20 W over 2 minutes, would that really matter?  Would anyone know the difference?

Comment: Wouldn't the loss across a shunt resistor heat things up? I don't know how much heat will be generated but certainly it will rise the temperature of the system to a considerable point which I don't want to. That's my only concern. I would have been able to measure the exact power loss across the regulator resistor if I had been able to calculate the value of the current across the shunt resistor. Nevertheless, I am dropping all my assumptions, and with your 3 decades of experience I am hoping that you would guide me as to how do I go about achieving my goal. That's all from me. Thanks.

Comment: @omsai: This is the first you mentioned about heat as a problem.  Before you worry too much about that, figure out how much power the motor actually puts out when a human is cranking it.  The shunt regulator (not shunt resistor) would have to be able to dissipate that continuously.  That would happen if someone kept cranking it for a long time, even when the cap was fully charged.  If dissipating the power is a problem, then other methods are probably better.  One possibility is a series shut off switch when the cap is full.

Comment: OK. So, how do I calculate the power generated? I know it generates around 10 V open circuit emf. How do I calculate the current at the regulator stage since about 7.5 V will have to drop across the regulator? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to power an LED and found the peak value of current at 3.5 V to be more than 50 mA. Since, I am directly powering the LED from the generator without any signal conditioning, I am not able to know the DC values.